# Weird keyboard behavior in Eclipse text editor for Shift+Alt+<arrow>, how to revert/debug this?

Tags: mac, eclipse

I am used to that behavior where Shift+Alt/Option in combination with arrow keys selects more or less of the text I started with, jumping to select next word and so on.

I seem to recall that Eclipse used to or does normally adhere to this convention (which I have successfully used in other editors like SciTE or Sublime Text). Does it not now?

Currently however, the selection jumps to encompass a whole lot of text due to some whole other algorithm than what I am used to - the selection jumps to include parent scope (Java editor).

I went as far as removing bindings for any and all (encountered) Shift+Alt+ combinations from Eclipse preferences (Keys pane), and it still behaves weird! It appears as when using Shift in combination with Alt/Option or Ctrl or Command, the selection attempts to eat up parent scope (as in declaration scope in Java - first anynomous scope or for/while loop scope, then method scope, then class etc).

The worst part of it is that I don't know what I may have changed and what is going on under the hood. How can I debug this problem? Can I enable some sort of tracing of which commands get executed in Eclipse internally as I hit the keys, so that I can pinpoint the grand cause of this?

The installation is fairly vanilla - Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary + Java Development Tools for Eclipse, Mac OSX 10.7 x86-64.